# Multiple Celery Remote workers

Tags: python, rabbitmq, celery

This question is regarding the use of multiple **remote** Celery workers on separate machines. The implementation of the App can be conceptualized as:

[image]

My App (Producer) will be adding multiple tasks (say 50) to the queue every 5 mins (imagine a python **for** loop iterating over a list of tasks to be performed asynchronously at every 5 min interval). I want the celery workers (which will be remote machines) to pick these tasks up as soon as they are pushed.

**My question is will Celery/RabbitMQ automatically handle task distribution (so no Worker picks up a task that has already been picked up by a worker from the queue - i.e. to ensure work is not duplicated) and distribute the tasks evenly so no worker is left lazying about while other workers are working hard or do these have to be configured/programmed in the settings?***

I would most appreciate it if someone could forward me relevant documentation (I was checking out Celery docs but couldn't find this specific info regarding remote celery workers in this context.)

Answer (score 3):

Automatically but you need to be aware of prefetching feature which is described here: http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/optimizing.html#prefetch-limits, read until the end of the page.

In short, prefetching works on two levels: worker level and process level, since a worker may have multiple processes. To disable prefetch on worker level you need to specify `worker_prefetch_multiplier = 1` in celery settings, to disable on the process level you need to specify `-Ofair` option in worker's command line.

Comment: Many thanks, will check out the docs! Can you also please direct me to the Celery docs where it specifies and/or gives details of task distribution as **automatic**, Thanks!

Comment: Also, since the Async task is just a bunch of identical HTTP REST calls (with each task being directed to a different appliance) does it make sense to achieve the concurrency using **Eventlet**: http://celery.readthedocs.io/en/latest/userguide/concurrency/eventlet.html#concurrency-with-eventlet

Comment: Cannot find any specific place about automatic nature. Routing may be what you need: http://celery.readthedocs.io/en/latest/userguide/routing.html. Also cannot say anything about Eventlet because I've never used it.

Answer (score 0):

So after digging around in RabbitMQ docs it seems that the default exchange method is Direct Exchange (ref https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/amqp-concepts.html) which means that tasks will be distributed to workers in a round-robin manner.